# Hi, I am working Node/express.js project, Sequelize as ORM and MySQL as DB. Could anyone know plz how fixed

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, environment-variables, sequelize.js

sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:245:13
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
throw err;
^

**Error: Cannot find module 'sequelize/types'**
Require stack:

- C:\VISSIONTECH\vissionTechApi\models\products.js
- 

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I'm new to the Sequelize NPM.
I solved the problem by commenting out the

```
 const { QueryInterface } = require("sequelize/types");
```